# What are the correct structures of the verb `consist`?

Tags: grammar

I was trying to think of different structures that `consist` can have and I thought of these:

```
Neural Network is consisted of nodes.

Neural Network consists of nodes.
```

I know that the second sentence is true but I feel like I've heard the first one being used. Is it correct?

Comment: The second version is grammatically correct, the first is not. See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/consist-comprise-or-compose)

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you! So, `compose` would be a correct verb to use in the first structure?

Comment: It would be grammatically correct, yes.

Comment: "Nodes composes a network" is correct obviously. But doesn't "A Network composes nodes" make any sense?

Comment: @xyz Firstly, why do you say `Nodes composes`? It's probably `compose`. For the second question, the network itself is composed of nodes so the network is composed of nodes.

Comment: Thanks, It's my mistake. However in my comment I pointed on the example: "A network composes nodes" that seems incorrect to me. You pointed on the example "A network is composed of nodes.". That is correct but beside of my point.

Comment: @xyz Hi and sorry for the late response. So, I believe the sentence you're saying isn't grammatically wrong but isn't intellectual. Switching up `network` and `nodes` make it sound rational. `Nodes compose a network.` that is the same as `Nodes create a network.`. If I'm getting you wrong, please let me know what the sentence you think seems incorrect to you means to you so that we can figure it out.